# Why am I losing time of day info, when sending date time as long in JSON format?

Tags: java, json, ajax, datetime

I am sending a quite big json String from server side to client side. The hierarchy includes long values which represents date time points. This functionality has been working for years now, but out of nowhere, the time of day is suddenly completely ignored client side. The only changes made to the application, is a migration from weblogic to JBoss application server. It is a Java/JSP web application.

Here is a simplified version of the json string sent from client side:

```
[{
    "startDate": 1513897200000,
    "endDate": 1515884400000,
    "testMap": {
        "720915": {
            "testruns": [{
                "datetime": 1515413387000,
                "status": "Passed",
                "testCycleID": 720915,
                "testID": 167753,
                "runID": 0
            }],
            "testInstanceID": 720915,
            "cycleID": 45229,
            "testID": 167753
        }
    }
}]
```

The startdate and endDate never has any time of day information. But the testruns -> datetime has. `1515413387000` represents `Mon Jan 08 2018 13:09:47 GMT+0100`

But here is a how the object received in the ajax function (copied from browsers console):

```
...
720915: 
    cycleID: 45229
    testID: 167753
    testInstanceID : 720915
    testruns: Array(1)
        0: {
            datetime: Mon Jan 08 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Rom, normaltid), 
            status: "Passed", 
            testCycleID: 720915, 
            testID: 167753, 
            runID: 0}
...
```

On server side, this is how I write the json to the HttpServletResponse object. the response object is of type HttpServletResponse:

```
String jsonTests = myCreationFunctionForTheJSONString();
response.setContentType("application/json"); 
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); 
out.print(jsonTests);
//this line below, creates the output in the first code example in the question.
System.out.println(jsonTests);
```

Finally, here is a snippet of the ajax function used to retrieve the JSON:

```
$.getJSON( "tests", 
    {id: ID},
    function(data) {
        console.log(data);
...
```

However, if I copy the JSON in the first example, and set it to a variable directly in the browser console (chrome), the long number is not interpreted as a date or datetime at all, and simply remains as a numeral.

Can anyone explain to me why and/or how this conversion between long and date/datetime happens? And if it shouldn't happen, and I am actually experiencing an error, are there any more steps left to debug?

Comment: In what datetime format you are converting this EPOCH into ??

Comment: I am not performing any conversion at all. The last line of my code example is simply writing the received data object to the console, directly after it is received. So it should really be a numeral here, unless there are some automatic javascript converting of json string formatted data.

Comment: It should not automatically convert your epoch or long millisecond into date time directly. Something is making it work that way, I doubt your key 'datetime' is making the difference and it is converting it. If possible try changing key to something else and then when you need Datetime convert it into whatever format you want.